# Detect underlying platform/flavour in Cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, platform

Does anybody know any cmake variable or hook or something which can give me underlying platform name/flavour name on which it is getting executed ?
e.g. Linux-CentOs
Linux-Ubuntu
Linux-SLES

I know cmake has "CMAKE_SYSTEM" variable but that doesn't help differentiating flavours of linux for e.g. Any help is appreciated.

edit :
I just read that it can be done using lsb_release command ?

Answer (score 27):

The following snippet populates the `LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT` cmake variable with information about the underlying Linux system:

```
find_program(LSB_RELEASE_EXEC lsb_release)
execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXEC} -is
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

On Ubuntu, for example, it yields `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Different distros put the same things in different places.  This was the perfect way to include libraries using those distro-specific locations.

Comment: Might want to wrap this with a succinct check for linux somehow.  Just learning cmake myself.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu for ARM64 and it says `No LSB modules are available.`

Comment: Do you have the `lsb_release` binary installed in your system? On Arch, for example, its package is called `lsb-release`.

Answer (score 11):

Slightly less convoluted than checking files on the filesystem is to deduce the best you can from the available CMAKE_SYSTEM vars. For instance a CMakeLists.txt file containing lines like this:

```
message("-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE}")
message("-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:      ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
message("-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
message("-- CMAKE_SYSTEM:           ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}")

string (REGEX MATCH "\\.el[1-9]" os_version_suffix ${CMAKE_SYSTEM})
message("-- os_version_suffix:      ${os_version_suffix}")
```

outputs this when I ran `cmake .` :

```
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE: Platform/Linux
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:      Linux
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: x86_64
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM:           Linux-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
-- os_version_suffix:      .el6
```

And for my situation, the `.el6` was enough to differentiate.

Comment: You capture only one digit, "\\.el[1-9]+" would be better idea IMHO ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Likely, you have to write such a test yourself. Here's one of the possible examples, just googled: https://htcondor-wiki.cs.wisc.edu/index.cgi/fileview?f=build/cmake/FindLinuxPlatform.cmake&v=4592599fecc08e5588c4244e2b0ceb7d32363a56

However depending on your actual needs the test may be quite complex. For example Ubuntu as a Debian-based OS always has `/etc/debian_version` and many RPM-based OSes traditionally have `/etc/redhat-release`. There's a file `/etc/os-release` in the Linux Standard Base (LSB) specification, but for example on the localhost this file is empty for an unknown reason :)

Comment: yeah the problem is quite complex and I am thinking of manually setting up the variable but just wanted to see if theree are any solutions out there.

Comment: Well, one of the possible implementation I've given above. For SuSE-based you may also look at `/etc/SuSE-release` Another possible solution is to detect "main flavours" (e.g. whether its `RPM`-, `DEB`- or `<YOU-NAME-THE-PACKAGE-MANAGER>`-based and then call a detected package manager and look for a specific package as described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37336/how-to-detect-sles-version)

Comment: Note that `/etc/os-release` will work on all systemd-based distributions, at minimum.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but as of now, there is still no `cmake` built-in function to find this information in good detail. I've implemented a small utility function that uses `lsb_release` on Linux to find a number of relevant system details:

```
function(get_linux_lsb_release_information)
    find_program(LSB_RELEASE_EXEC lsb_release)
    if(NOT LSB_RELEASE_EXEC)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not detect lsb_release executable, can not gather required information")
    endif()

    execute_process(COMMAND "${LSB_RELEASE_EXEC}" --short --id OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    execute_process(COMMAND "${LSB_RELEASE_EXEC}" --short --release OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_VERSION_SHORT OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    execute_process(COMMAND "${LSB_RELEASE_EXEC}" --short --codename OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_CODENAME_SHORT OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

    set(LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT "${LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    set(LSB_RELEASE_VERSION_SHORT "${LSB_RELEASE_VERSION_SHORT}" PARENT_SCOPE)
    set(LSB_RELEASE_CODENAME_SHORT "${LSB_RELEASE_CODENAME_SHORT}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Add it to your `CMakeLists.txt` and use it like this:

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
    get_linux_lsb_release_information()
    message(STATUS "Linux ${LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT} ${LSB_RELEASE_VERSION_SHORT} ${LSB_RELEASE_CODENAME_SHORT}")
endif()
```

If you need further details, check what else `lsb_release` can provide with `lsb_release -a`.

Note that not every Linux has `lsb_release` installed. Most systems provide it, but its not mandatory. On newer Ubuntu, for example, its the default on desktop installs, and required by `ubuntu-minimal`. If it should be missing on your machine, you can install it with `sudo apt install lsb-release`.

Answer (score 1):

on my machine

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE == "Platform/Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME == "Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM == "Linux-<kernel version>"
```

obtained with `cmake --system-information`, I know of people that use said macros in their own `CMakeLists.txt` files so they work as expected, probably `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` is what you really want but here you go, you get this 3 and the command to inspect the properties of your machine as far as `cmake` is concerned .

Comment: Unfortunately a version of the Linux kernel is usually the least significant characteristic of a given Linux installation. Technically I could setup a really ancient kernel on my workstation. Well, likely then I would also need to downgrade or specifically compile LIBC... Well, with some "core software".

Comment: @user3159253 that's why I added the command, that command gives you anything you need to know to compile your software

Comment: Nope, I have a Ubuntu-based distro and it doesn't tell anything about that, it doesn't even tell me my actual distro (KDE Neon). Gotta use `uname`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [thiagowfx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592428/2506817), If you want to get the *codename* of the distro (if it is available):

```
execute_process(COMMAND lsb_release -cs
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE RELEASE_CODENAME
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

E.g. in Ubuntu 14.04 the variable `RELEASE_CODENAME` will hold `trusty`.

Answer (score 1):

```
### find our os (wins, centos, ubuntu, etc)
set(VAR_OS "")
IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
        MESSAGE(DEBUG "Linux")
        execute_process (
                COMMAND bash -c "awk -F= '/^ID=/{print $2}' /etc/os-release |tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\"'"
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE outOS
        )
        MESSAGE(DEBUG "Linux os: ${outOS}")
ELSEIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
        MESSAGE(DEBUG "Windows")
        set(VAR_OS "wins")
ELSE()
        MESSAGE(FATAL "No OS detected!")
ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
```